# Application crashed on setContentView android with no stack trace

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, build.gradle

Application crashed when it executes the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in my mobile **samsung galaxy s4 android 5.0 custom** it works fine. but i tried 3 other (android 4.0+) mobiles and bluestack it application crashed.

i can't track the bug where is wrong in my app. there is no **stack trace** of exception, application just crashed and closed silently.
any help!

issue is not with layout file because it works fine on my mobile only.

Layout is drawer layout and using fragment.

here is build.gradel

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.iorzb.malik.proximity"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile files('libs/your jar volley.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
}
```

here is manifest file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iorzb.malik.proximity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".Help.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



</application>
```

**here is actvity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Here is app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.iorzb.malik.proximity.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Here is nav_header_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_proximity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here isactivity_main_drawer.xml (navigation menu)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_home_black_36dp"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_map"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_directions_car_black_36dp"
            android:title="Driving Directions" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_stores"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_shopping_cart_black_36dp"
            android:title="My Stores" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_new_stores"
            android:icon="@drawable/signup_icon"
            android:title="New Stores" />
    </group>


</menu>
```

**Here is MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

Comment: you should post both your xml layout and your activity code. If it works on android 5.0 doesn't mean that your layout xml is bug free

Comment: application doesnt crash without logcat report. perhaps u r missing something.

Comment: i added xml and java code here. thanks for the response.

Comment: @MalikRizwan Do you use Vector Drawables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the solution. i just removed the image view from  **nav_header_main.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_proximity" />
```

it worked fine. i don't know how but it worked. can any one tell what is wrong in this imageview,
or any thing is missing.

Comment: issue was with drawable xml in line
android:background="@drawable/round_corner"

Answer (score 0):

This issue is in google library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

Please remove all v7:23.2.0 and install anyother.Your code automatically work.
Just change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

hopefully you will solve your problem.

Comment: i removed the toolbar and then try but no luck.

Comment: please check my updated answer hope this will help you.